# DMA (Direct memory access)

Tags: microcontroller, dma

I have been studying DMA provided by the Infineon in XMC4100 & XMC4200 microcontroller series. I have questions that are listed below, everyone will be highly appreciated to answer them and help me to understand the working of DMA. If you find any question IP specific then kindly give its general answer.

1. When DMA is a flow controller, in which condition hardware
   handshaking interface will be used or software handshaking interface
   will be used for either source or destination peripherals?
2. Is the hardware handshaking interface also includes single and burst
   request signals along with request and acknowledge signals?
3. When source or destination peripheral is flow controller then why
   hardware handshaking interface is not supported?
4. When DMA is a flow controller (means DMA knows the block size and
   DMA should transfer the data using maximum possible bursts and where
   possible using single or early-terminated burst), then why do
   peripherals request for single or burst transactions?
5. For peripheral-to-memory, memory-to-peripheral and
   peripheral-to-peripheral single or multi-block transfers, if the
   peripheral is either source or destination then address to read from
   source and address to write on destination should be fixed
   throughout the single or multi-block transfer. Is this a correct
   statement?
6. I have confusions in DLR (DMA Line Router) that how it selects a set
   of service sources from a set of DMA compatible service sources?
   Then how the selected service sources are further used for hardware
   handshaking? Kindly refer me to any resource from which I can
   understand the working of DLR. And also refer some resources for
   priority Mux for handling hardware requests from DLR.

Comment: You might want to edit this wall of text into something readable. Empty rows, bulleted lists and so on.

Comment: firstly, get the terminology correct - DMA is the technique. You're asking questions regarding a DMA controller. whether you choose burst or single transfer depends on the peripheral. For example the spi peripheral sends/receives one byte (for example) at a time - you can't do burst as there may be significant time between each byte being received/sent. I think you should spend some time understanding what you would use the dma controller for - then the various options should start to make more sense.